# MassTransit: run execute routing-sleep synchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, masstransit, routing-slip

I'm looking for how to execute `routing-sleep` in a blocking way. 
I need to run routing-sleep from `http` request, not from mass-transit `request/response` and to return success in case all activities were finished and failure in case of activity failure.

I'm aware about subscriptions of the routing-sleep builder.
The problem that called to `IPublishEndpoint.Execute` resolved immediately after the first activity endpoint is reached.

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790009/masstransit-wait-for-all-activities-to-complete-and-then-continue-processing).
For my case, it says the I need to post `masstransit` request to myself from ASP.Net controller.
Is there any better way to ensure where all activities can be completed ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the unit tests of using a Request proxy to execute a routing slip, and you'd just use the request client in your controller. It isn't documented, nor is it easy to understand if you aren't familiar with routing slips and MassTransit, but it sounds like what you're trying to do.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/tests/MassTransit.Tests/Courier/RequestRoutingSlip_Specs.cs

Comment: Thanks, Worked for me. I see that it is based on subscriptions, Completed and Faulted subscriptions are added by base class. In case im subscribing to RoutingSlipEvents.All then completed and Faulted events are fired twice. Is that by design?

Comment: If you create an additional subscription, then yes, you would get the message twice since there is already a subscription.